# Ampersand in email address/nickname?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have received email from an external person addressed to `x&y@domain.com` instead of `xny@domain.com`. (**&** is a valid character in email addresses.) It is caught in the catchall and I would like to add it as an alias/nickname of `xny@domain.com` but it isn't allowed. I'm thinking of putting a forwarding rule in the catchall, but this requires the user to click and approve.

Are there any other options?

For instance, the `x+y@domain.com` routes to `x@domain.com` automatically, but this doesn't seem to do that since both `x@domain.com` and `y@domain.com` already route to `xny@domain.com` as nicknames/aliases.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in policy when it comes to regular Gmail and Google Apps.

While in regular Gmail, you can use most symbols such as `@`, `&`, `%`, and `+`, these cannot be used in a Google Apps account.

Google Apps Guidelines: https://support.google.com/a/answer/33386?hl=en
Gmail: http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html